# How do I register a copied file in the assets directory with the manifest in Vite?

Tags: javascript, vite

I have the following Vite config. It uses the viteStaticCopy plugin to copy the file into the `.public/vite/assets` directory. I have it listed in the config as an entrypoint but build doesn't put it in the manifest and so when I try to include that file in code it throws an error that that file cannot be found in the manifest. Where is this code going wrong? The copy plugin does successfully copy `config.js` to `./public/vite/assets` but build does not include it in the manifest.

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    RailsPlugin(),
    EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV', 'ENVIRONMENT']),
    nodePolyfills({
      include: ['buffer', 'crypto', 'stream'],
      globals: {
        Buffer: true,
      },
    }),
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: path.join(__dirname, 'app/javascript/components/config.js'),
          dest: 'assets',
          transform: {
            encoding: 'utf8',
            handler: () => {
              return `window.env = ${JSON.stringify(appEnvironmentVars)};`;
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  entrypoints: {
    config: './assets/config.js',
  },
  build: {
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
});
```

I tried running vite build with this config and though `config.js` did appear in the `./public/vite/assets/` it did not appear in the manifest. I did delete all manifest files before running build so that nothing was cached.